# PostgreSQL List Tables without Schema Tables

Tags: postgresql

After reading through the PostgreSQL documentation I determined that I can create an *absolute* list of table names in PostgreSQL using the following query...

```
SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables ORDER BY tablename ASC;
```

This generates something alone the lines of (reduced example list)...

> my_table_1
>
> my_table_1
>
> pg_aggregate
>
> pg_am
>
> pg_amop
>
> sql_features
>
> sql_implementation_info
>
> sql_languages

Unfortunately this also lists tables with prefixes such as `pg_` and `sql_` which I presume are part of the database schema.

How do I list tables using a `SELECT` query that are not part of the schema?

I already know how to do this using `\dtM` command in PSQL command line though it doesn't serve my purposes in this instance.

In example I would like only the following to be returned instead...

> my_table_1
>
> my_table_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use the [`information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) for queries like this:

```
select *
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public';
```

Alternatively:

```
select *
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

`information_schema.tables` filters out the `temp` schemas already.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');` worked great. Wish my laptop screen was HD so when psql outputs a command (so I can use it visually) I could see the data without wrap enabled. Using that to analyze differences between schema and public for example.